# Pull non-binary files from git stash

Tags: git, git-stash, git-apply

I'm pretty new to git.  On one computer I ran

```
git stash save myfeature
git stash show -p > myfeaturepatch
```

I copied `myfeaturepatch` to a second computer and ran

```
git apply myfeaturepatch
```

I made some changes which included adding some font files (binaries) and then ran

```
git stash save myfeature2
git stash show -p > myfeaturepatch2
```

When I try to apply this second version back to my first computer, I get

```
error: cannot apply binary patch to 'myfont.ttf' without full index line
```

My guess is I needed to run `git stash save --binary myfeature2` when I made the stash.  Unfortunately, since `git stash` deletes the changes it saves to the file, and since I can't apply my patch to either computer due to the above error, I don't currently have access to the changes I made.

I've tried a bunch of different `git apply` and `git stash` commands, but I don't have a complete enough understanding of what's going on and what the arguments mean to pull out just the non-binary files from my patch file.  I assume there's a way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My guess is I needed to run `git stash save --binary myfeature2` when I made the stash.

No, this is unnecessary ... and not even an option anyway: there is no `save --binary`.

What `git stash` does is *commit your work*.  It just does this in a weird way, using two separate commits,<sup>1</sup> that are on *no* branch.

As long as you still have the stash, you still have the commits.

The easiest way to deal with a stash that you still have, that requires picking apart, is to convert it to ordinary commits on a new branch:

```
git stash branch newbranchname [<stash>]
```

Of course, this requires that you do it on the machine that *has* the stash,<sup>2</sup> but once done, you are on a new branch, with the index the way it was when you ran `git stash save`, and the work-tree the way it was when you ran `git stash save`.  (The new branch's current commit is the commit that was *current* when you ran `git stash save`, as well.)  You can now finish `git add`-ing any unstaged files, `git reset` any files you don't want staged, and `git commit` the resulting index (and then make more commits from more work-tree files until everything is safely saved in ordinary non-stash-y commits).

---

<sup>1</sup>The two commits are for the current *index*, and the work-tree.  Remember that the index is where you are building the next commit you will make, by `git add`-ing and/or `git rm`-ing things to copy the latest version from the work-tree.  Either or both of the index and work-tree can therefore be different from the current *commit*, so `git stash save` saves both, separately, so that it can restore them separately later, if you want that later.  You can tell it to save a third commit containing untracked files, or all files, too.

<sup>2</sup>Of course, before you `git stash branch`, you should have a clean index and work-tree.  If you do not, you will need to commit or stash first.  If you decide to stash again, this pushes your previous stash "up" one level, so if it used to be `stash@{2}` it is now `stash@{3}`.  I find that keeping many stashes active is a recipe for madness: instead, commit on a new branch.

Answer (score 0):

Try at least ([`git apply`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply)):

```
 git apply --reject mypatch.diff
```

> This option makes it apply the parts of the patch that are applicable, and leave the rejected hunks in corresponding `*.rej` files.

And when you make a patch ([`git diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)), add the `--binary` option to:

> output a binary diff that can be applied with `git-apply`.